# How to implement NegEx in PL/sql?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

My skill at Regular Expressions is marginal at best. However I have a task where I need to read medical type text, and tag different types of words. Additionally I need to determine if the term is negated. It would appear that there is a set of routines written in Python and ported to Java that do the type of thing I need. They are called Context/Negex, and can be found here; [Google Code Negex Project](https://code.google.com/p/negex/)

I can sort of read Java, and I understand some of what they are trying to do. My understanding is they do a term scan the sentence for the term tagging the terms, and then loop through a group of "negation phrases" and tag the negative terms, and change the original term tag to negative.

My first question, is anyone aware of an Oracle port of this type of routine? (One option is to implement the java version as an Oracle Java Stored Procedure, but I would find that difficult to modify & support).
If not, I have a question about regular expressions;

The problem: Replacing subsets of previous replacements without nesting.

Say I have a string that contains;

> dog elephant dog cat cat dog mouse

I then want to tag two phrases

```
1) dog cat 
2) dog
```

Edit: Needs to handle dog as a discrete word and would not match dogfish or fishdog like below;

> dog elephant dog cat cat dog dogfish fishdog mouse

I would replace all "dog cat" with "dog cat" yielding;

```
dog elephant <term id=123 type=pos>dog cat</term> cat dog mouse
```

I now need to replace all of the term "dog" except the ones already in any tag starting with "" with "dog" yielding:

```
<term id=456 type=pos>dog</term> elephant <term id=123 type=pos>dog cat</term> cat <term id=456 type=pos>dog</term> mouse
```

Can Regular Expression do this? If so, what would the regular expression be that would cause regexp_replace to ignore anything within "" tags?

I implemented the approach outlined below as;

```
  FUNCTION ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(IN_TEXT IN VARCHAR2, SEARCH_TERM IN VARCHAR2, TERM_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, RECORD_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN CLOB
  IS
    REGEX_SEARCH VARCHAR2(512);
    REGEX_REPLACE VARCHAR2(512);
  BEGIN
    REGEX_SEARCH := '((<TERM.*?</TERM>|[^<])*?)(^|\W)('|| SEARCH_TERM ||')($|\W)';
    REGEX_REPLACE := '\1 <TERM ID='|| TO_CHAR(RECORD_ID)||' TYPE=' || TERM_TYPE ||'>'|| SEARCH_TERM ||'</TERM> ';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGEX_SEARCH = ' || REGEX_SEARCH);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGEX_REPLACE = ' || REGEX_REPLACE);
    RETURN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(IN_TEXT, REGEX_SEARCH, REGEX_REPLACE,1,0,'in'));
  END ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM;
```

And it works well with the sample text, but when I try it with a simpler string like;

```
SELECT ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(UPPER('elephant dog cat cat dogfish fishdog mouse'), 'DOG CAT', 'POS', 123),'DOG', 'POS',456) 
FROM DUAL;
```

I end up with;

```
ELEPHANT <TERM ID=123 TYPE=POS <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> CAT</TERM> CAT DOGFISH FISHDOG MOUSE
```

It seems to eat one of the trailing ">" and nests a tag.

All additional help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_replace(  
  'dog elephant <term id=123 type=pos>dog cat</term> cat dog mouse',
  '((<term.*?</term>|[^<])*?)dog', 
  '\1<term id=456 type=pos>dog</term>'
)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4737b4/1)

Comment: That works well for what I asked. Unfortunately I wasn't clear. the word dog in the search string needs to be a discrete word not part of another word. So it should not match "dogfish". I tried `code`'((<term.*?</term>|[^<])*?)(^|\W)dog(\z|\W)'`code` and it worked, except it ate the space before and after dog.

Comment: I have added a bit to my question above. If you have a minute, I would appreciate if you would look at it.

Comment: Change `\W` to space character.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (
      REGEXP_REPLACE (source_string,
                      '(^| +)(dog cat)($| +)',
                      ' <term id=123 type=pos>\2</term> '),
      '(^| +)(dog)($| +)',
      ' <term id=456 type=pos>\2</term> ')
```

Demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16707).

Comment: What about `cat, dog, fish` ?

Comment: That is why I used \W instead of a space. What I ended up doing so far is `code`trim(regexp_replace( 'dog elephant <term id=123 type=pos>dog cat</term> cat dog dogfish mouse fishdog dog', 
                            '((<term.*?</term>|[^<])*?)(^|\W)dog($|\W)', '\1 <term id=456 type=pos>dog</term> ' ))`code`